# How to make delete method in django extra action?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was able to use [extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to make an endpoint when I want to POST an ImageTag (ManyToMany Field) to my Image. I was also able to use `lookup_field` to make CharField instead of pk for accessing each Image.

This is my sample endpoint when adding ImageTag:

```
POST localhost:8000/my_app/images/IMG_123/image_tags/
```

I can POST something like this to the endpoint:

```
{"image_tags": ["Urban", "Vegetation"]}
```

This my source code:

```
#models.py
class ImageTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
    image_id = models.CharField(unique=True)
    image_tags = models.ManyToManyField(ImageTag, blank=True)
    ...

#serializers.py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'

class ImageTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_tags = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image_tags',)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data

#views.py
class CaptureExtraAction(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get', 'post', 'delete'])
    def image_tags(self, request, image_id=None):
        image = self.get_object()
        data = request.data.copy()

        image_tags = request.data.get('image_tags')
        if image_tags:
            data['image_tags'] = []
            for tag in image_tags:
                obj_, created = ImageTag.objects.get_or_create(
                    defaults={'name': tag},
                    name__iexact=tag
                    )

                image.image_tags.add(obj_)

            data['image_tags'] = image.image_tags.all()

        serializer = ImageTagSerializer(image, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class ImageTagViewSet(ImageExtraAction, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    lookup_field = 'image_id'
    ...

#urls.py
router.register(r'images', ImageTagViewSet, basename='image')
```

My next task is allowing DELETE method to remove an ImageTag from the object.
For example, I want to remove "Urban" in the ImageTag for Image IMG_123, I want to have this kind of endpoint:

```
DELETE localhost:8000/my_app/images/IMG_123/image_tags/Urban
```

can also be:

```
DELETE localhost:8000/my_app/images/IMG_123/image_tags/?name=Urban
```

How will add this to my current extra action viewset?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for very same answer. I think this should help
[someway.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions)

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['put'], name='Change Password')
def password(self, request, pk=None):
    """Update the user's password."""
    ...

@password.mapping.delete
def delete_password(self, request, pk=None):
    """Delete the user's password."""
    ...
```